# Alamofire Enhancement of validate()

Tags: swift, protocols, alamofire

I have to apply web service api which also return response with status code which are not 200...<300.Means there are also response json inside 400,500,404,etc.But,I found that Alamofire validate() and it return .Success and .Failure.But,unfortunately, .Success didn't catch the response of 400,404,500.So,I really do need enhancement of Alamofire validate() to meet my requirement.So,any help with that?

For now i did like that

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

protocol RequestTokenAPIProtocol{
    func didSuccessRequestToken(results:JSON,statusCode : Int)
    func didFailRequestToken(err : NSError)
}

class RequestTokenAPI{

var delegate : RequestTokenAPIProtocol
init(delegate: RequestTokenAPIProtocol){
    self.delegate=delegate
}

func post(requestURL:String,param:[String:String]){
    Alamofire.request(.POST, requestURL, parameters: param)
        .response { request, response, data, error in
            if error != nil{
                self.delegate.didFailRequestToken(error!)
            }
            let json = JSON(data: data!)
            self.delegate.didSuccessRequestToken(json,statusCode: (response?.statusCode)!)
    }
}

func doRequestToken(){
    post(REQUEST_TOKEN,param:["":""])
}

}
```

So,I can handle the response json which will be return when we have 400,404 status code.Is there any way that I can do like that at Alamofire?

```
func post(requestURL:String){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, requestURL, parameters: nil)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    self.delegate.didSuccessRequestToken(json)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                self.delegate.didFailCheckingHeader(error)
            }
    }
}
```

I really need help for my usage which seem its better or not?If there is a better way to handle response,please guide me because I am beginner at Alamofire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should specify the expected status codes in the call to `validate`. Let's assume your valid expected codes are 200, 400,500, 404. Then you don't even have to check the response result, just verify that the response carries no error, according to the documentation of the `validate` method:

> If validation fails, subsequent calls to response handlers will have an associated error.

So in your case, I think your code could be simplified as following (I'm assuming that the `JSON` class that appears in your code is SwiftyJSON):

```
Alamofire.request(route)
        .validate(statusCode: [200, 400,500, 404])
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) -> Void in
            if let error = response.result.error {
                self.delegate.didFailCheckingHeader(error)
            } else if let jsonObject: AnyObject = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(jsonObject)
                self.delegate.didSuccessRequestToken(json)
            }
        })
```

It should work like that. Otherwise, you might want to check if the server is actually returning the expected status codes

Comment: Thanks @Luis ,I really want more answers.I do have one question.If the status code is 501,will it go to "else if" from your code?

Comment: Exactly, 501 isn't a valid status code (not passed in `validate` method) thus Alamofire will call `responseJSON` with an NSError in `response.result.error`... The server shouldn't send a payload if it responds with a 501, therefore `response.result.value` will be nil and the `else if`block would execute... But if you want to ensure this happens, you can alter the code to check for the error first. I have edited my response to do the error handling first

Comment: Just to be clear about the above comment, he is saying the the `else if` block will be executed. `else if` *used to be the error block* but since the answer was updated it is now the valid object block. So with the code above, `else if` would not be executed if a `501` came back. Only the error block. Cheers!